# If 'X' div is visible, 'Y' div is hidden. If 'X' Div is hidden, 'Y' div is visible

Tags: jquery, hide, slideshow, show

I'm building a website, and have a slideshow.
The slideshow has captions, and has an index, that overlays over the entire page.
When the overlay is activated, the captions need to disappear. 
And when the overlay is deactivated, by either clicking the exit button, or a thumbnail link, or a menu link, the captions must come back.

This is what i have so far

```
    if($('#indexpage').css('display') == 'none'){ 
    $('#imageinfo').css('visibility') == 'visible'} 
    else { 
    $('#imageinfo').hide('slow'); 
    }
```

I cannot for the life of me, figure out how to get it working.
Any help would be muchly appreciated.

thanks,

Comment: It might be hard to do but the title of this question is very vague. Could you come up with a better one so others might benefit when having the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

In your code that controls showing or hiding of one element or the other, you should simply use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle):

```
$("#indexpage,#imageinfo").toggle();
```

Then each time `.toggle()` is called, the one that is visible will be hidden, and the one that is hidden will be visible.

This assumes that you have already set your css to have one showing and the other hidden by default.  So, your page's CSS should contain:

```css
#indexpage {
    display: none;
}
```

If that doesn't work for you, and you still want to show or hide one based on whether the other is visible, use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) passing a boolean parameter indicating whether to show or hide the element.  Get that boolean value by using [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is) and [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector).

```
$("#imageInfo").toggle(!$("#indexpage").is(":visible"));
```

**Edit:** Just to note, there are a couple of reasons your example is not working.

**First,** you seem to be trying to use `.hide()` with `.css("visibility")`.  But, `.hide()` sets an element's `display` to `none`.  Once that is set, the `visibility` value will have no effect.  The corollary to `.hide()` is `.show()`.  But `.toggle()` may be preferred at times, as it encapsulates the functionality of both `.hide()` and `.show()`.  This is particularly true when you want to show or hide an element depending on a certain condition.  In this case, pass a boolean to `.toggle()` indicating whether the element should be visible.  You can reduce your code from this:

```
if (checkSomeCondition()) {
    $("#myElement").show();
}
else {
    $("#myElement").hide();
}
```

To just one line of code:

```
$("#myElement").toggle(checkSomeCondition());
```

**Second,** the other reason your code is failing is that you are evaluating the value of `visibility` rather than assigning a visibility value.  The `==` operator is the equality operator, which compares two values and returns a boolean.  To assign a value, you need to use the assignment operator (`=`):

```
var a = 1;
a == 2;  // returns false, a is unchanged
a = 2;   // now a is 2
```

But, you wouldn't use the assignment operator in this case, because you can't assign a value to the result of a function call.  Ie, `someFunction() = 1` is invalid JavaScript.  In jQuery, to read a value, you use a single argument.  To write a value, you pass a second argument, indicating the new value:

```
$('#imageinfo').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

This corrects the syntax, but because of the first issue above, it doesn't solve your problem - you'd need to set `display` instead of `visibility`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('#indexpage').css('display') == 'none')
$('#imageinfo').show('slow'); 
else
$('#imageinfo').hide('slow');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use selector.is(":visible") like so:

```
if ( $( "#x" ).is(":visible" ) ) {
    $( "#x" ).hide( "slow" );
    $( "#y" ).show( "slow" );
} else
    if ( $( "#y" ).is(":visible" ) ) {
        $( "#y" ).hide( "slow" );
        $( "#x" ).show( "slow" );
    }
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/envy/7YBLg/)

Comment: Thanks, didnt work. None of these have actually. maybe somethings conflicting with other plugins somewhere. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

If you like single line solutions, you can try:

```
$('#y').css('display', $('#x').is(':visible') ? 'none' : 'block');
```

Comment: Or, shorter: `$('#y')[ $('#x').is(':visible') ? "hide" : "show" ]();`

Comment: +2 - sweet. I didn't know we could give func names as strings. i.e. till i saw the [] way of accessing you've used.. Pretty cool..

Comment: It's one of those "clever" techniques that is cool in a small number of situations but the rest of the time just makes the code harder to read and thus harder to maintain. But definitely something to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks, didnt work. None of these have actually. maybe somethings conflicting with other plugins somewhere. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that  `visibility` is your `Cssclass` then try

```
  $('#imageinfo').addClass('visibility').show('fast');
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your explanation, the second line of your code:

```
$('#imageinfo').css('visibility') == 'visible'
```

seems to be trying to set the `'visibility'` CSS property, but what it is actually doing is comparing the current value associated with that value with the string `'visible'`, and the result of that comparison is not being used for anything. Even if you replaced the equality comparison operator `==` with the assignment operator `=` it would still be incorrect because it doesn't make sense to try to assign the return from that function equal to a string. The correct syntax to *change* the property is as follows:

```
$('#imageinfo').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

But you can also use `.show()` as the opposite of `.hide()`. So:

```
if($('#indexpage').css('display') == 'none'){
   $('#imageinfo').show('slow');
} else {
   $('#imageinfo').hide('slow');
}
```

As far as fitting that in with whatever other code you have, I'd first need to see your other code, specifically how you've set up your event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read this article on the differences between hide, fade and animate. I just mention it because if anything is positioned relatively on your page with respect to the hiding/showing elements, the differences in these techniques can really screw up the layout.

http://www.catchmyfame.com/2010/08/31/jquery-hide-vs-fadeout-vs-animate/

Since you are going to be using this in a number of different scenarios, I would build 2 functions that you can call.

HideOverlay, which removes the overlay and makes the index visible.

ShowOverlay, which removes the index and makes the overlay visible.

Inside these you can have the toggles. If you are hiding the index separately from the overlay in other scenarios within your script, make another function, and call it from within the hideOverlay/showOverlay.

(Others could probably suggest making a singular function for this overlay hiding/showing by passing a true/false variable, but I like to keep it simple until I know what is going on and then refining it when I fully understand how it works)